# Using MySQL in R for Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, r

How to use MySQL in R (statistic language) for Windows (7)?

There is no problems then using linux:

```
install.packages('RMySQL')
library(RMySQL)
...
```

But I found no such package for Windows on CRAN. There is only [note](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/r-release/ReadMe) about this fact.
I found [package for version 2.10](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/classes/s133/RMySQL_0.5-11.zip), but it is not usable in 2.12.1.

Also tried

```
install.packages("RMySQL", type="source")
```

but got an error :

```
* installing *source* package 'RMySQL' ... 
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'RMySQL'
* removing 'C:/.../R/win-library/2.12/RMySQL'
```

**Is there any way to connect to MySQL database from R in windows?**

Comment: Are you using 32/64-bit R with a 64/32-bit MySQL?  That could break things.

Comment: @RichieCotton Windows 7 x64 R and MySQL -32 bit. Unable to install package.

Comment: @RichieCotton MySQL runs fine and several programs connects to it successfully. Everything except windows is 32 bit. The problem is with installing this package. I just do not know there to start.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found solution with help of **ran2**, who gave me link to [common question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785933/adding-rmysql-package-to-r-fails). The basic process is described [here](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/RMySQL), but there are several hints, So I will describe the whole solution *(please change the R version and paths if needed)*:

1. Install latest RTools from [here](http://www.murdoch-sutherland.com/Rtools/)
2. install MySQL or header and library files of mysql
3. create or edit file `C:\Program Files\R\R-2.12.1\etc\Renviron.site` and add line like `MYSQL_HOME=C:/mysql` (path to your mysql files)
4. copy libmysql.lib from mysql/lib to mysql/lib/opt to meet dependencies.
5. copy libmysql.dll to `C:\Program Files\R\R-2.12.1\bin` or to `windows/system32` directory.
6. run `install.packages('RMySQL',type='source')` and wait while compilation will end.

Thanks to all who tried to answer.

Comment: Thanks for posting your own solution here, I'm sure it will be helpful to other people who might have a similar problem.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to follow these instructions. I find my MySQL installed in `C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL`, so I made the content as `**MYSQL_HOME="C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL"**`. But coming to the 4th step, I find the `libmysql.lib` file in `lib` folder all right, but I can't find any `opt` folder in `lib`. What should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785933/adding-rmysql-package-to-r-fails/4792884#4792884). However, my suggestions is to try WAMP which comes as a one click install. Admittedly you get more than you need (webserver) but the MySQL installation runs pretty well.

Comment: There are no issues about mysql server. Thanks for link. I have followed it and found a solution. It is not so straightforward so I had described in separate answer. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the MySQL headers and libraries, as explained in the [installation instructions](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/INSTALL). Please do read the documentation before turning to SO.

Comment: have you succeeded? What compiler should be used? Should I install MS Visual studio (what version?), mingw or some other compiler? No answers there.

Comment: @Yuriy unfortunately I can't install software on my work computer so I can't really test it out. It has been awhile since I've done this on Windows, but I don't remember it being terribly difficult. I think I just installed MySQL (from [mysql.com](http://mysql.com) and then installed RMySQL with `install.packages("RMySQL", type="source")`.

Comment: tried this: `R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="--with-mysql-dir=C:\mysql" -l ".../R/win-library/2.12" RMySQL_0.7-5.tar.gz`
and failed with same errors :(