# Error Connecting to MySQL server using RMySQL

Tags: mysql, r, database, rmysql, dbconnection

I am getting the following error when I try to connect to a MySQL database using RMySQL package.
I am trying to connect to a host and not my local system. The previous discussion posted with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431961/connect-to-mysql-database-with-rmysql?rq=1) is on a local host

> *Failed to connect to database: Error: Access denied for user 'user'@'IP*' (using password: YES)*

IP* The full IP Address is displayed

I wrote the following statement in R

```
mydb = dbConnect(dbDriver('MySQL'), user='user', password='password', dbname='db-name', host='host name',port=Port #)
```

I am able to connect to the  server using MYSQL bench using the same credential on my local system.

Any Idea what I might be missing here?

Comment: Do don't really add any information that this question doesn't already have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431961/connect-to-mysql-database-with-rmysql?rq=1 Probably should be closed as a duplicate unless you can add more information to make the problem reproducible or include error logs.

Comment: The issue in that link was solved since the user was using double quotes instead of single quotes.  I was able to connect to the server using the same credentials in the SQL Workbench. I don't have a clue as to what I am missing