# How to install RMysql on Windows 7 with proxy settings

Tags: mysql, r, windows-7, rmysql

I am fighting with the installation of RMysql on R2.13.0 on Windows 7 64bit.  The version of my mysql 5.5, 64bit. Here are the steps, which led me to an error:

1. Install RTools
2. Set up proxy by calling: `setInternet2(TRUE)` after [FAQ@CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#The-Internet-download-functions-fail_002e)
3. Set MYSQL_HOME: `Sys.setenv("MYSQL_HOME"="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\")` after [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785933/adding-rmysql-package-to-r-fails/4792884#4792884)
4. Call in R Console: `install.packages("RMySQL", type="source")`

After 4, I got the following error:

```
Installing package(s) into ‘C:/Users/Foo/Documents/R/win-library/2.13’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://artfiles.org/cran/src/contrib
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘RMySQL’ is not available (for R version 2.13.0)
```

Alternative to 4 is just to install the package: `install.packages("RMySQL")`. In this case I got:

```
Installing package(s) into ‘C:/Users/foo/Documents/R/win-library/2.13’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://artfiles.org/cran/bin/windows/contrib/2.13
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘RMySQL’ is not available (for R version 2.13.0)
```

I am sure that I do not have problems with connection, because I can call R update. 
Could anybody help me to find out how I can access mysql db from R?

ps. Here is output from sessionInfo()

```
R version 2.13.0 (2011-04-13)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

**UPDATE:** I connected directly to the internet without the proxy, now I got:

```
> install.packages("RMySQL", type="source")
Installing package(s) into ‘C:/Users/foo/Documents/R/win-library/2.13’ (as
‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'http://ftp.yalwa.org/cran/src/contrib/RMySQL_0.7-5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip'
length 160769 bytes (157 Kb) opened
URL downloaded 157 Kb

* installing *source* package 'RMySQL' ... ERROR: configuration failed for
package 'RMySQL'
* removing 'C:/Users/foo/Documents/R/win-library/2.13/RMySQL'

The downloaded packages are in
        ‘C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpaUw1Tj\downloaded_packages’
Warning messages: 1: running command
'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-213~1.0/bin/i386/R
CMD INSTALL -l
"C:/Users/foo/Documents/R/win-library/2.13"
C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpaUw1Tj/downloaded_packages/RMySQL_0.7-5.tar.gz'
had status 1  2: In
install.packages("RMySQL", type = "source") :
   installation of package 'RMySQL' had non-zero exit status


    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] tools_2.13.0
```

Comment: So far, my solution: a virtual machine on Win7 + xubuntu + R + RMySQL +  Rstudio.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the double check the repository you are using. It seems to me it should be

```
install.packages("RMySQL", repos='http://artfiles.org/cran.r-project.org/')
```

or something similar. You can check by trying to open the URL you posted in a browser.

Comment: Nop. It does not solve the problem.