# Use RJDBC MySQL

Tags: r, jdbc

I read out that is not so easy to run RMySQL package see [here](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/RMySQL) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785933/adding-rmysql-package-to-r-fails). Rather I found this [site](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/2010/09/connecting-to-sql-server-from-r-using-rjdbc/) and asked my self if it is possible that I could use JDBC MySQL driver from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=414248) with the RJDBC package? And how to setup it.

Comment: You probably can, why don't you try it? The instruction for SQL Server you link to can be used for other Type 4 JDBC drivers as well; you just need to use the right JDBC url and the right driver.

Comment: Those links refer to installation and do *not* indicate that running RMySQL is difficult.  I have used RMySQL over a period of years and for me it worked well and I suspect better than the alternative you are considering.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, sorry you are right, what I want to say is it seems for me that is difficult, because I cant follow the steps what to do that RMySQL will run on my machine.