# RMySQL fails to install on 32 bit Windows 7 system

Tags: r, gcc, rmysql

I know that this problem has been discussed many times in this forum and I have followed all the steps explained at the page: [adding RMySQL package to R fails (on Windows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785933/adding-rmysql-package-to-r-fails) and http://martin.von-gagern.net/howtos/20110728-rmysql/

My OS is is Windows 7, 32 bit and despite following all the steps to modify path and to add the libmysql.lib, mysqlclient.lib and libmysql.dll files to the folders, my installation terminates with the error.

> gcc.exe: error: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.6/lib/opt/libmysql.lib: No such file or directory no DLL was created!

I can see that the `libmysql.lib` exists in the opt folder. I have googled for this genre of errors but didn't get a clue on what is wrong. Is this an issue with the `gcc` compiler? Help is much appreciated.

P.S. The installation succeeded with on a 64 bit system with the given instructions, therefore please be specific for 32 bit windows 7.

Comment: To add to my woes, on another 32 bit windows 7 system the error was different:- <br/> *gcc.exe: error: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6/lib/opt/libmysql.lib: Invalid Argument no DLL was created*

Comment: @Andrie, thanks for editing code, gives me an opportunity to learn.