# How to select MySQL version when installing RMySQL in linux

Tags: mysql, r, docker, rmysql

I am running an R application in a Docker container and would like to connect to a MySQL 8 database using the RMySQL library. I can connect to the database from the container using the `mysql` terminal command without any problems, but when I call `dbConnect()` in my R script I get an unknown SSL connection error (see below).

As I am using the same SSL certificates with the terminal command as well as in my R script, it must have something to do with the MySQL version used by RMySQL. I need to have MySQL 5.7 installed in the container, too, as some other R packages cannot be built otherwise. However, according to the thread below you can specify the directory of the MySQL version to be used when installing RMySQL:

[adding RMySQL package to R fails (on Windows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785933/adding-rmysql-package-to-r-fails-on-windows)

So I set `$MYSQL_HOME` in `/etc/R/Renviron.site` and called `install.packages('RMySQL',type='source')`.

Apparently you also need to copy some .lib and .dll files to make it work in Windows, but where do I find the equivalent files in Linux?

Database handler script:

```
#' @import DBI
#' @import RMySQL

connectToDatabase <- function(myproject.db_config) {
  dbConfig <- read.properties(myproject.db_config)
  print(dbConfig)

  dbHandle <- dbConnect(
    MySQL(),
    dbname = dbConfig$databaseName,
    host = dbConfig$host,
    port = as.integer(dbConfig$port),
    user = dbConfig$user,
    password = dbConfig$password
  )
  return(dbHandle)
}
```

Config file passed to the `read.properties()` command:

```
host=domain.subdomain.de
port=3306
user=john.doe
password=mypassword
databaseName=my_db
ssl-ca=/staging/mysql-ssl/ca.pem
ssl-cert=/staging/mysql-ssl/client-cert.pem
ssl-key=/staging/mysql-ssl/client-key.pem
```

Error message in R:

> Error in connection_create(host, username, password, dbname, as.integer(port),  :
>    Failed to connect: SSL connection error: unknown error number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. The SSL certificates were not applied in the `dbConnect()` call. They need to be defined in a `mysql.cnf` file which is passed to `dbConnect()` in the `default.file` parameter:

```
dbHandle <- dbConnect(
    MySQL(),
    dbname = dbConfig$databaseName,
    host = dbConfig$host,
    port = as.integer(dbConfig$port),
    user = dbConfig$user,
    password = dbConfig$password,
    default.file = dbConfig$configFile
)
```

Config file passed to the `read.properties()` command:

```
host=domain.subdomain.de
port=3306
user=john.doe
password=mypassword
databaseName=my_db
configFile=/staging/config/mysql.cnf
```

**mysql.cnf**:

```
[mysqld]
ssl-ca=/staging/mysql-ssl/ca.pem
ssl-cert=/staging/mysql-ssl/client-cert.pem
ssl-key=/staging/mysql-ssl/client-key.pem
```